# GSM Interference - SIM800L

Tags: microcontroller, rf, wireless, gsm

I did a GSM based alarm system using SIM800L modules.One is transmitter & the other one is receiver.When the transmitter button pressed it will make a call to receivers number & receiver detects this number & make an alarm. The system works fine on workbench.

But when I install this receiver in a police station its not working.Police station there are plenty panels like RF alarm panels, GSM panels, CDMA panels etc…

My panel is a plastic panel (housing is plastic).& it powered from a step down transformer (not a torodial).

How can I solve my problem? Is this interference?

Comment: What happens if you call the receiver from a phone?

Comment: Good question. When I call from a phone its working (I can hear the dialing).